# BreadCrumbs Navigation Visualization in hierarchical way

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, breadcrumbs, graph-visualization, pydot

I have breadcrumbs like the following

```
Home -> Patio, Lawn & Garden -> Farm & Ranch

Home -> Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry -> Uniforms, Work & Safety
etc...
```

I need to build a tree visualization for entire breadcrumbs. I have around 45k such breadcrumb records. I also looked up something similar to this - https://codepen.io/blackjacques/pen/ZPMpza

But are there better and easier way to this in python or any programming language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no one answered the question and I found my own way of doing it I would like to post the answer myself

D3.js already has a feature of tree visualization. The only thing we need to do is to convert the breadcrumb navigation to the format needed by the D3 library. 
You can use a python library called `anytree` that constructs the tree and also exports to different formats. Else we can write own python scripts to do so (I believe in not reinventing the wheel). Then use `D3.js` `tree` visualization to build the tree visualization.

I have automated the whole process in the github - https://github.com/Better-Boy/BreadCrumb-Navigation-Visualizer